# Implementation of Bayes Weighted average formula for my new website

Tags: bayesian, weighted-mean

Im planning to implement Bayes weighted average formula (which imdb uses) for my new reviews and ratings website for mobile phones. The formula is under

S=wR+(1−w)C

where
S= score of the product
R= average of user ratings for the product.
C= average of user ratings for all products.
W= weight assigned to R and computed as v/(v+m), where v is the number of user ratings for that product, and m is average number of ratings for all products.

Im contemplating to divide the mobile phones into price segments and calculate the bayesian scores for phones in those segment unlike the way   IMDb does.

Q Going about segment wise, am I correct in doing it ? Or should I take the whole mobile phones segment of all the products to arrive at the bayesian estimate since two of the aspects of bayesian estimate are average ratings for all phones and the prior m calculated as = average number of ratings for all phones. 
I need to define what the term 'all phones mean'.

Comment: How do you define "reliable"?

Comment: @tim. Will the scores be effective enough to be reliable in the 2 cases mentioned in question 1&2 ?

Comment: Effective in what? To judge effectiveness you must have some criteria for it.

Comment: @tim I'm trying to find out if the formula can be universally applied.

Comment: Universally applied to what?! $E=mc^2$ is quite universal.

Comment: @tim.Universally applied to the cases mentioned above.is that clear enough ?

Comment: @tim let others give in their answers.

Comment: @tim , the criteria that there will only be a few products to deal with. Can the Bayes formula be applied then ?

Comment: you need at least one product, otherwise you don't have any data to calculate it. As it was stated in the notice for putting your question on hold: it is not clear what you're asking.

Comment: Hello Tim, I have edited the question. It should bring some clarity.

Comment: And the answer is still the same: you can apply it to any number of products, single product at minimum (then it does nothing, same as usual mean of single point is the same value)...

Comment: @tim.thanks.what if the number of ratings for each of  those 12 products is very low in number say <15. Can the scores calculated be relied upon ?

Comment: Starting again: How do you define "reliable"?

Comment: The criteria that there are only a few ratings as mentioned. Can the Bayes formula be applied ?

Comment: This is not a criteria for ratings to be reliable. Moreover, this is not a "Bayes formula".

Comment: Of course the number of ratings are important, aren't they, once they cross a threshold say >50, they become more believable. OK ?

Comment: @tim. Sorry for late reply. Since the bayesian estimate can be applied to minimum two products at least, what will be the value of the average rating. Would it be calculated from those 2 products only ?

Comment: I'm considering the value of m to be 50 at the minimum for the bayesian scores to be considered believable after they have been computed using - average number of ratings for all products. Am I doing it correctly ?

Comment: I've edited the question.